# Javascript \\b string escape problems

Tags: javascript, string

Sorry for the probably stupid question, but I'm trying to make a string beginning with "\begin" (I'm building a LaTeX document). I can't figure out how to get it to parse correctly. Just replacing `\` by `\\`  works fine in `"\end"` -- I can just type `"\\end"`. The problem seems to be that `\b` is used to in regular expressions. I thought `"\\" + "begin"` might work, but that seems to give the same behavior. What's the best way to get around this in general, considering that I'm likely to run into a lot of this?

Comment: `'\\end'` probably works in a regular expression because `\e` doesn't have a special meaning, unlike `\b`. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't escape it properly, as described in zzzzBov's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the `\` with another `\` works for me fine:

[image: Console]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ah964/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- the problem was actually the method I was using the write the string to a file, where the same encoding issue came up again. It's now working!

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape character within JavaScript strings. If you want a string to include the `\` character, you must use an additional `\` character:

`'\\'` evaluates to a string containing `\`.

`\` is an escape character within JavaScript regular expressions. If you want a regex to include the `\` character, you must use an additional `\` character:

`/\\/` evaluates to a regex that matches `\`

Regular expressions built using strings therefore need to double-escape the `\` character, once for the string, and once for the regular expression:

`new RegExp('\\\\')` evaluates to a string that contains `\\`, which evaluates to a regex that matches `\`.

To get the regex to match `\begin`, you just need to suffix the regex with `begin`:

```
/\\begin/               //regex literal
new RegExp('\\\\begin') //regex constructor
```

Comment: And `'\\e'` probably worked because `\e` has no meaning in a regex (afaik), but `\b` does.